# Error: A driving SObject type has already been set, all other entity types in the FROM clause must be relationships to the initial object

Tags: apex, soql, batch, lookup-field

I am trying to launch a batch job with scope below

```
Select id, Expiry_date_of_your_license_to_trade__c, Has_Live_Contract__c, Licence_Reminders_Sent__c, 
       Proprietor_First_Name__c, Proprietor_Email_Address__c, 
       Operator_Main_Contact_Email__c, Main_Contract_Email_Lookup__c, 
       Main_Contact_Lookup__c 
from Bid_Information__c 
where Has_Live_Contract__c = True 
      and (Licence_Reminders_Sent__c < 1 or Licence_Reminders_Sent__c = NULL) 
      and Main_Contract_Email_Lookup__c != \'\' 
      and (Expiry_date_of_your_license_to_trade__c <='+ String.valueOf(expdate) +' and Expiry_date_of_your_license_to_trade__c != NULL)
```

While everything works fine in the Sandbox, I am getting error during Validation on the production server

> A driving SObject type has already been set, all other entity types in the FROM clause must be relationships to the initial object.

Comment: Probably an issue with the conversion of the expiry date to an SOQL date format string. Would be better if you used a binding instead of inserting a literal.

Comment: David, thanks a lot for your response. Eventually, I took out the date filter completely but still get the same error.  Is it possible that the issue is with the lookup formulas that I include in the query string? For example  'Main_Contract_Email_Lookup__c' , which is a lookup formula field in Bid_Information__c that returns a value from Contact object.